# Thymeleaf: How to properly specify HTML name and Id attribute in case of nested List entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The entity contains nested Lists. With th:each, I can see the values get displayed on the form but no update is getting persisted in the database and sure this is because of incorrect 'name' and/or 'id' attributes specified which Thymeleaf is not transcoding. How do I specify them?

I tried with different combination of name and Id  and following the documentation, but none of them worked. Tried with just th:each loop variable, but that did not work either too.

Main Entity:
CustomAttributesMap.java

```java
@Entity
public class CustomAttributesMap implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private EntityType entityType;

    @ElementCollection
    //@ManyToMany
    private List<CustomAttributesFieldMap> customAttributesFieldMapList = new ArrayList<>();
// setter and getter code
...
}
```

First child List:
CustomAttributesFieldMap.java

```java
@Entity
public class CustomAttributesFieldMap implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private CustomFieldType fieldType;

    @ElementCollection
    //@ManyToMany
    private List<CustomAttribute> customAttributesList = new ArrayList<>();
// setter and getter methods.
...
}
```

Second child list:

```java
@Entity
public class CustomAttribute implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private boolean required;
    private String value;
// setter and getter methods
....
}
```

Controller.java

```java
...
@ModelAttribute("customAttributesMapList")
    public List<CustomAttributesMap> populateCustomAttributes() {
       return customerAttributeMapService.findAll();
    }


@PostMapping("/customAttributeCustomization")
    public String saveCustomAttributeCustomization(
        List<CustomAttributesMap> customAttributesMapList, Model model) {
        Logger.getLogger(WebController.class, "Logigng for WebController").error(""
                + "customAttributesMapList " + customAttributesMapList);
        for(CustomAttributesMap customAttributesMap: customAttributesMapList) {
            customerAttributeMapService.save(customAttributesMap);
        }
....
```

CustomAttributesEdit.html

```html
<form class="user" th:action="@{/customAttributeCustomization}" th:object="${customAttributesMapList}" method="POST">
..
<div class="card p-3 collapse" style="max-width: 50rem;" th:each="customAttributesMap, iterIndex: ${customAttributesMapList}" th:id="${customAttributesMap.entityType}">
..
<div th:each="customAttributeFieldMap, iterStat : ${customAttributesMap.customAttributesFieldMapList}">
...
<table align="left" id="alphaTable" class="table table-sm table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr class="d-flex" id="theadRow">
<th class="col-7 text-center" >Name</th>
<th class="col-3 text-center" >Mandatory</th>
<th class="col-2 text-center">Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr th:each="customAttribute, rowStat : ${customAttributeFieldMap.customAttributesList}" class="d-flex" th:id="rowalpha-+${rowStat.index}">
<td class="col-7">
<input class="form-control"  type="text" th:value="${customAttribute.name}"  th:id="customAttributesMapList+${iterIndex.index}+.customAttributesFieldMapList+${iterStat.index}+.customAttributesList+${rowStat.index}+.name" name="customAttributesMapList[+${iterIndex.index}+].customAttributesFieldMapList[+${iterStat.index}+].customAttributesList[+${rowStat.index}+].name"/> 

</td>
....
</table>
</form>
```

I am expecting that in the above form, the value of customattribute.name need to be edited and persisted in the database, which currently is not happening. Upon debugging on the controller, the main entity list (CustomAttributesMapList) is unchanged and do not contain any user updates on the HTML form. Sure this is due to the above code with incorrect name and id for the input field, couldnt get that right.

**Update** 
Ok, I couldn't find any helpful answer so I flattened the entities to have single entity `CustomAttrubute` which has both entityType and fieldType properties and have `CustomAttributesMap` (list) which contain the `CustomAttribute` entity and this map will be the form object sent to the front end from web controller. But I would like to review if anyone has got an answer to the Thymeleaf puzzle :) .

Comment: Your `CustomAttributesMap` member name is `customAttributesFieldMapList` but your form field is named `customAttributesMapList`. Shouldn't these match?

Comment: @Phil, The form object is a list of CustomAttributesMap (called as customAttributesMapList) and each CustomAttributesMap has a field (which is a list of CustomAttributesFieldMap) called customAttributesFieldMapList, so I guess the code is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use @RequestMapping instead of @PostMapping

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/customAttributeCustomization",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCustomAttributeCustomization(
        List<CustomAttributesMap> customAttributesMapList, Model model) {
        Logger.getLogger(WebController.class, "Logigng for WebController").error(""
                + "customAttributesMapList " + customAttributesMapList);
        for(CustomAttributesMap customAttributesMap: customAttributesMapList) {
            customerAttributeMapService.save(customAttributesMap);
        }
```

Comment: Updated the question with post method from the controller. It just saves the list to the db. No special logic.

Comment: For now I found you are using '@PostMapping' annotation which I never used before. Generally I used '@RequestMapping' annotation.